# Change Map Marker icon in Mit App Inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

[image: MIT App Inventor code image]

I make one Android App with Maps in MIT App and I have to create marker on the certain place and I have to change it's icon and size. What is wrong with this code, because I get error message "Unable to load SVG from assets". Thank you so much in advance!!!

Comment: Look at the picture above.

Comment: Just briefly looking at it, make sure any images/assets start with a lower case letter, as it looks like the image name is made up of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the // in the image name, that should do it.